# comment / uncomment line on on pgadmin 4 with german keyboard

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

is there a way to comment / uncomment a line on pgAdmin 4.20 on german keyboards (QWERTZ)?

Commenting works with shortcut `CTRL` + `/`. Unfortunately, neither (Ctrl + ÷) on the numpad nor 
`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `7` is working.

Would be great if anyone could suggest a solution.

Thank you and best, 
Tobias

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out that `CTRL` + `#` works on german keyboards in pgadmin 4.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in pgadmin 4 Version 6.15